# Starting Go server on App Engine localhost throws error

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Can anyone tell me why this is happening:

```
$ dev_appserver.py nmg_server
INFO     2017-07-08 17:15:37,369 application_configuration.py:461] No version specified. Generated version id: 20170708t171537
WARNING  2017-07-08 17:15:37,369 application_configuration.py:166] The Managed VMs runtime is deprecated, please consider migrating your application to use the Flexible runtime. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating for more details.
INFO     2017-07-08 17:15:37,472 devappserver2.py:116] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2017-07-08 17:15:37,513 api_server.py:312] Starting API server at: http://localhost:54096
INFO     2017-07-08 17:15:37,517 api_server.py:938] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2017-07-08 17:15:37,517 api_server.py:941] Saving search indexes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 103, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 97, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 381, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 369, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 196, in start
    options.api_host, apiserver.port, wsgi_request_info_, options.grpc_apis)
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 223, in start
    _module.start()
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 1647, in start
    self._add_instance()
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 1799, in _add_instance
    expect_ready_request=True)
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/go_runtime.py", line 189, in new_instance
    self._go_application.maybe_build()):
TypeError: maybe_build() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I'm trying to run my server for testing on localhost and it keeps exiting with this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Cloud SDK which is affecting `dev_appserver.py` when using with `App Engine Managed VMs`. It does not seem to be affecting App Engine Standard or App Engine Flex environments.

Until Google releases a new Cloud SDK with the fix, you can modify the `CLOUD_SDK_INSTALL_DIR//platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/go_managedvm.py` file locally as shown below (added both the patchable unified diff as well as before/after just for convenience).

Also consider moving to App Engine Flex since [Managed VMs are deprecated and will not be supported after October 27, 2017](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/upgrading).

> **Warning**: The Managed VMs beta environment (applications deployed with
>   `vm:true`) is deprecated and will be decommissioned. This page is for
>   users who are already using the flexible environment with `vm:true` in
>   their `app.yaml` and want to upgrade to the latest release. If you are
>   updating your application from the standard environment, see the
>   [Migrating Services from the Standard Environment to the Flexible
>   Environment instead](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/migrating).

### Diff in patchable format

```
--- /Users/tuxdude/google-cloud-sdk-orig/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2go_managedvm.py     2017-07-08 11:11:11.000000000 -0700
+++ /Users/tuxdude/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/go_managedvm.py      2017-07-08 11:11:11.000000000 -0700
@@ -152,15 +152,9 @@
     logging.debug('Build succeeded:\n%s\n%s', stdout, stderr)
     self._go_executable = exe_name

-  def maybe_build(self, maybe_modified_since_last_build):
+  def maybe_build(self):
     """Builds an executable for the application if necessary.

-    Args:
-      maybe_modified_since_last_build: True if any files in the application root
-          or the GOPATH have changed since the last call to maybe_build, False
-          otherwise. This argument is used to decide whether a build is Required
-          or not.
-
     Returns:
       True if compilation was successfully performed (will raise
         an exception if compilation was attempted but failed).
@@ -173,9 +167,6 @@
       self._work_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp('appengine-go-bin')
       atexit.register(_rmtree, self._work_dir)

-    if self._go_executable and not maybe_modified_since_last_build:
-      return False
-
     if self._go_executable:
       logging.debug('Rebuilding Go application due to source modification')
     else:
```

### Before:

```
  def maybe_build(self, maybe_modified_since_last_build):
    """Builds an executable for the application if necessary.

    Args:
      maybe_modified_since_last_build: True if any files in the application root
          or the GOPATH have changed since the last call to maybe_build, False
          otherwise. This argument is used to decide whether a build is Required
          or not.

    Returns:
      True if compilation was successfully performed (will raise
        an exception if compilation was attempted but failed).
      False if compilation was not attempted.

    Raises:
      BuildError: if building the executable fails for any reason.
    """
    if not self._work_dir:
      self._work_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp('appengine-go-bin')
      atexit.register(_rmtree, self._work_dir)

    if self._go_executable and not maybe_modified_since_last_build:
      return False

    if self._go_executable:
      logging.debug('Rebuilding Go application due to source modification')
    else:
      logging.debug('Building Go application')
    self._build()
    return True
```

### After:

```
  def maybe_build(self):
    """Builds an executable for the application if necessary.

    Returns:
      True if compilation was successfully performed (will raise
        an exception if compilation was attempted but failed).
      False if compilation was not attempted.

    Raises:
      BuildError: if building the executable fails for any reason.
    """
    if not self._work_dir:
      self._work_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp('appengine-go-bin')
      atexit.register(_rmtree, self._work_dir)

    if self._go_executable:
      logging.debug('Rebuilding Go application due to source modification')
    else:
      logging.debug('Building Go application')
    self._build()
    return True
```

Comment: I'm not even intending to use managed VM's and I don't have anything (that I can see in my app.yaml file that would make GAE think that either....I'd like to use Flex or Std (whichever supports endpoints)

Comment: runtime: go  
    api_version: go1  
    service: default  
      
    env: flex  
    threadsafe: yes  
      
    instance_class: F1  
    automatic_scaling:
  
    beta_settings:  
      # Enable Google Cloud Endpoints API management.  
      use_endpoints_api_management: true  
      # Specify the Swagger API specification.  
      endpoints_swagger_spec_file: swagger/swagger.yaml

Comment: thats my app.yaml above.....I couldn't figure out how to make it line-break

but I don't see anything in there about vm
perhaps some of the beta commands are confusing appengine
I want to use task-queues so it seems I need to go with GAE standard (not flex) 
will that prohibit my use of endpoints?

Comment: @Dewey - I'm not too familiar with Cloud Endpoints integration with App Engine. On a quick search I found [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/get-started-frameworks-java) which mentions support for Java 8 and Python runtimes with App Engine standard. In theory, I don't see a direct reason why Go runtime will not be supported since the endpoints are just plain HTTP, but there might be some limitations. Can you give that a shot - using GAE standard with Cloud Endpoints (using the tutorial as a reference) ?

Comment: yes...that's a good tutorial and I have looked at it
but until I can figure out why appengine thinks I'm trying to use managed VM's and get around that deploy problem, I'm not clear how that tutorial will help me.  Do you see anything in my app.yaml that implies VM & should be causing this "maybe_build() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)" crash?

In other words, how do I get back to Standard or Flex so I don't have to patch Googles code or deploy to the wrong GAE infrastructure?